Stream Writer returns: Terminated with exception: Wrong basePath ... for the root path
I have a PySpark Notebook in Microsoft Fabric with a stream reader (read parquet files) and a stream writer (writes delta tables).
When I run my notebook I get the following status from my stream writer:

{'message': 'Terminated with exception: Wrong basePath file:/synfs/notebook/ecaaa1e6-26d7-4cad-b82e-0498d158d7d5/temp_mnt/Files/d/_processing/cases for the root path: file:/synfs/notebook/cec3158c-a799-4b71-8a22-2ff374946b04/temp_mnt/Files/d/_processing/cases/cases-d-20240926165049.parquet', 'isDataAvailable': False, 'isTriggerActive': False}

I have no idea where the root path is comiong from and the ID in the root path URL "cec315..." doesn't look realted to my code and enviroment at all.
Here's some steps I do in my notebook.
I mount the default Lakehouse to a temp mount point. Then I use the synfs URL to access the Table and File structure of the lakehouse within my notebook. All works fine so far. Except the stream writer.
Here's important parts of the code:
Stream Reader
cases = (
    spark.readStream
    .schema(schema)
    .format("parquet")
    .load(source_processing_path)
)

source_processing_path is 'file:///synfs/notebook/ecaaa1e6-26d7-4cad-b82e-0498d158d7d5/temp_mnt/Files/d/_processing/cases'
upsertToDelta-function
def upsertToDelta(microBatchOutputDF: DataFrame, batchId: int) -> None:
  """Upsert records from the micro-batch DataFrame into the Delta table."""

  # Add a column to track the source file of the data
  upsert_data = microBatchOutputDF.withColumn(
    "_fabric_source_file", input_file_name()
  ).withColumn(
    "_update_date",notebookruntime
  )

  # Deduplicate Batch
  window_spec = Window.partitionBy("Id").orderBy(col("LastModifiedDate").desc())
  deduplicated_data = (
    upsert_data.withColumn("row_num", row_number().over(window_spec))
    .filter(col("row_num") == 1)
    .drop("row_num")
  )

  # Perform the upsert operation
  merged = (
    target_table.alias("c")
    .merge(deduplicated_data.alias("u"), "c.Id = u.Id")
    .whenMatchedUpdateAll()
    .whenNotMatchedInsertAll()
    .execute()
  )

Stream-writer
stream_writer = (
    cases
    .writeStream
    .option("checkpointLocation", f"{base_path_tables}{table_name}/_checkpoints")
    .option("path", source_processing_path)
    .foreachBatch(upsertToDelta)
    .trigger(availableNow=True)
    .outputMode("update")
    .start()
)

Stream writer status check
status = stream_writer.status
print(status)

This status check is where I get the message:

{'message': 'Terminated with exception: Wrong basePath file:/synfs/notebook/ecaaa1e6-26d7-4cad-b82e-0498d158d7d5/temp_mnt/Files/d/_processing/cases for the root path: file:/synfs/notebook/cec3158c-a799-4b71-8a22-2ff374946b04/temp_mnt/Files/d/_processing/cases/cases-d-20240926165049.parquet', 'isDataAvailable': False, 'isTriggerActive': False}

I'd appriciate any help.
I already tried solutions ChatGPT gave me like:

adding .option("path",source_processing_path) to my stream writer
adding .option("basePath",source_processing_path) to my stream writer

Of course looked for similar reports in stackoverflow, but I didn't find anything promising yet
